# Solutions of $ax^3+by^3=1$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

The solution of the question [A cubic diophantine Equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659266/a-cubic-diophantine-equation/3486315#3486315) depends upon being able to find non-zero  integer solutions of the equations $ax^3+by^3=1\text{ or }3$, where $a$ and $b$ are given positive integers.

I am aware of Selmer's work on equations of the form $ax^3+by^3+cz^3=0$ but I imagine that there might be much stronger results when we in effect know $z=1$. Does anyone know of such results or see how one might proceed?

Comment: You can obtain some solutions for x by setting b=0 and assuming a is non-zero. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ax%5E3%2Bby%5E3%3D1

Comment: Thanks - but integer solutions are required with $a,b$ positive.

Comment: Equation $aX+bY=1$ has infinite solutions of form $X=b t+X_0$ and $Y=-a t+ Y_0$ , among them $X=x^3$ and $Y=y^3$ may be found. This depend on values of a and b.

Comment: For example $X=3t+8$ and $Y=-47t-125$ give infinite solutions, one of them is $x=2$ and $y=-5$. There may be more solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equations $F(x,y)= k$ where $F$ is homogenous can be solved via factorizations and solutions to [Thue equation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue_equation)

If factorization is possible, say:
$$
G(x,y)H(x,y) = k
$$
then the approach is to split into cases and solve for all possible divisors $r$ of $k$, i.e. set $G(x,y) = k/r$ and $H(x,y)=r$.

After factorization degree $\leq 2$ equations are the usual Pell equations and degree $\geq 3$ is solved as Thue equations. In particular Thue equations only have finitely many solutions.

---

Unfortunately the only easy way I know for solving it is via existing computer programs.

A PARI/GP example:
$$5x^3-2y^3=7$$
Since $5x^3-2y^3$ is irreducible so this is already a Thue equation. This PARI/GP command can solve it:

> thue(thueinit(5*x^3 - 2,1),7)

Note that the second "1" indicates no assumptions (GRH). You can try it [here.](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/gp.html) This will return

> %1 = [[1, -1], [3, 4]]

and indeed $(X,Y)=(1,-1),(3,4)$ are both solutions. Other softwares like MAGMA and Sagemath can solve it too.

Comment: Great - thanks very much for this clear explanation. I've meant to look up Thue's Theorem for a while and not got round to it until now.

Comment: I learned it via Theorem 3.35 of Silverman's "Arithmetic of Dynamical Systems", which is pretty short and quite simple, but it uses the really difficult Roth's Theorem which I still don't understand. Maybe there's a more comprehensive version out there.

Comment: Thanks for this reference. I was thinking of working through the proof given in Dickson, Introduction to the theory of numbers. On a quick skim, the proof there seems elementary and self-contained but very, very long.